# Fetch a div via jQuery in SharePoint site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint-2010

In a sharepoint site I have the following div that I need to call it. Problem is in SP sites the id is dynamic and it is bad idea to use, but I don't know any other way to call the div? 
Any suggestion?

```
<span dir="none">
<div class='ms-rtestate-field ms-rtefield' style=''>
<div id='_ctl00_TextField_inplacerte_label' style='display:none'>Rich text 
editor no & (Title)</div>
 <div class=' ms-rtestate-write ms-rteflags-0' 
 id='_ctl00_TextField_inplacerte' style='min-height:42px' aria-
  labelledby='_TextField_inplacerte_label'  contentEditable='true' >
 <div class="ms-rtestate-field"> no & (Title) field value.
  </div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div></div>
<span dir="ltr">
```

Comment: Which div you want to call? Is class="ms-rtestate-field ms-rtefield" is also dynamic

Comment: <div class=' ms-rtestate-write ms-rteflags-0' 
 id='_ctl00_TextField_inplacerte' style='min-height:42px' aria-
  labelledby='_TextField_inplacerte_label'  contentEditable='true' > that is the one I want to call

Comment: Ano no the class="ms-rtestate-field ms-rtefield" is not dynamic

Comment: I have post a answer let me know if it can resolve your problem.If not tell what stuck i will resolve it.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your approach, I need to avoid using the div id as it is dynamic. Would you please explain your solution?

Comment: Once your view will render(asuming your view render on page load)..then you can do same with id as mentioned in answer but if your view is getting changed from ajax or other operation at client end then you should go with class.

Comment: Can you explain when you want to get this value like on page load, on click on that particular div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below line.You can get same also from class name

```
var divId = $('.ms-rtestate-write').attr('id');
console.log(divId);
```

Now you can do whatever you want with this Id or you can do same manipulation from class also.

let me know if it solve your problem.If you have multiple parrallel div with this div then let me know i will share it.

Comment: I think I got your idea, it worked for me :) thanks for helping

Comment: Thanks @dolly_do even i also explained in answer as well can you vote up this question so it can help other to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way I used long time back -

```
$(window).load(function(){
  var getDivFromitsPositioninLayout = $(".parent-div-class div:(n)th-child")
})
```

Got hold of the div based on the layout, but not sure if that fits in your criteria.